# echo file names containing 'a' and 'b' in either order

Tags: shell

I have a list of files as follows:

```
$ echo *
add akfefg aka ab ba
```

I want to echo file names containing both 'a' and 'b' in either order. I tried

```
echo *[ab]*[ba]*
aka ab ba
```

and it also prints 'aka'. I've tried

```
$ echo *a*b* && echo *b*a*
ab
ba
```

it does its job but 'ba' is printed in next line. Is there a simpler way to do this? Thank you.

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55359/how-to-run-grep-with-multiple-and-patterns

Comment: See also: [How to open or list all files whose name matches two patterns in Bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/287070) or [list files whose name meets 3 different criteria](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/396481) and [Find files containing multiple words where the order of the words does not matter](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/614599)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this answer, I'm addressing two different scenarios:

1. You want to match the filename that contains both `a` and `b` in the current directory *and then you want to do something to these files*.
2. You want to process the output of your two `echo` commands to remove the newlines.

If you want to loop over the filenames, then it would be good to have a single pattern that matches all names and then uses the expansion of that pattern in a loop.  Using `echo` would not be advisable as this removes the distinction between individual filenames.

In the `zsh` shell, the single pattern `(*a*b*|*b*a*)` would expand to all names where the letters `a` and `b` occur in any order.

In the `bash` shell, you could use the single extended globbing pattern (or `ksh`-like globbing pattern) `@(*a*b*|*b*a*)` to do the same thing.  The `bash` shell does not enable extended globbing patterns by default, so you would need to enable these with `shopt -s extglob` first.

In the `bash` shell, therefore, you could use something like

```bsh
shopt -s extglob

for name in @(*a*b*|*b*a*); do
    # process "$name" here
done
```

Another way to generate the wanted filenames *for processing* is by using `find`:

```bsh
find . ! -name . -prune -name '*a*' -name '*b*'
```

This looks in the current directory (only) for any name that contains both `a` and `b`.  You would then call some other utility using `-exec` at the end of this command to perform the operation, for example with

```bsh
find . ! -name . -prune -name '*a*' -name '*b*' -exec sh -c '
    for name do
        # process "$name" here
    done' sh {} +
```

Here, `find` generates the filenames used by the in-line `sh -c` script. See also [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705)

However, *if this is a text-processing exercise* and the purpose is to arrange two or more lines of text (the output from your two `echo` invocations) into a single line, then you'd do this by piping the text through `paste -s -`. This would additionally remove any newlines embedded in filenames.  Using `paste` in this way rather than `tr -d '\n'` (which also removes newlines) ensures that the resulting text is terminated by a single newline at the end.

Comment: See also `print -r -- *a*~^*b*(N)` (or `echo -E -`) in `zsh -o extendedglob` to print space-separated and followed by a newline. Or `print -r -- *a*~^*b*(N:q)` for that list to be both human readable and post-processable. Or other quoting variants like `() { print -r -- ${(q+)@}; } *a*~^*b*(N)`

Answer (score 2):

No need to use square brackets they are for matching characters from a range. In the second example you used `&&` operator, it's for executing multiple commands in sequence. That's why files are printed line by line.

Just run `$ echo *a*b* *b*a*`

That will print all files in a single line.

***Edit for redundant matching like `cacbca`;***

Extended globbing can be used, first enable it in bash `$ shopt -s extglob`

Then redifine the pattern as:

```
$ printf '%s ' @(*a*b*|*b*a*)
```

@(pattern-list)   Matches one of the given patterns

Comment: Beside that `echo` should be changed to printf. There is the issue that `cacbca` will be  printed twice. And, after all files are joined by spaces there is no clean way to divide that string into filenames again if those filenames could contain spaces and/or newlines.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. Is there a way to use echo to do the job instead of printf though? Thank you.

Comment: No, `echo` is the wrong tool for this job.

Comment: The problem with `cacbca` can be solved by using `find` in the first place. The question asks for a simpler way. `find` is not simpler, but it's probably a proper way.